# Collection allowing multiple, predefined types

Tags: java, generics, collections, types, interface

As the question states, is it possible to define a collection which allows only a set of predefined, and potentially unrelated types (I.e. which do not extend from a common object). This sort of thing:

```
List<Foo|Bar> list = new ArrayList<Foo|Bar>();
list.add(new Foo());//Allow
list.add(new Bar());//Allow
list.add(new Baz());//Disallow
```

Since I have never seen this done before, I am assuming it is probably not possible. If not, then is there a good reason for why not?

One solution I guess would be to have each necessary class inherit an empty interface, then set the type of the list to this interface. Would this be considered 'normal' practice?

Comment: Yes, the use of a "marker interface" is OK in this case.

Comment: Ah, everything is easier when you know what to google!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible (assuming `Foo` and `Bar` have no common super class other than `Object` and no common interface).

The reason:

Suppose it was possible :

```
List<Foo|Bar> list = new ArrayList<Foo|Bar>();
list.add(new Foo());//Allow
list.add(new Bar());//Allow
```

Now, what type would `list.get(0)` return?

Neither of these two lines can pass compilation, since `list.get(0)` can't be of both types:

```
Foo foo = list.get(0);
Bar bar = list.get(0);
```

This means the only thing that can compile would be :

```
Object obj = list.get(0);
```

and that has no advantage over using the raw `List` type.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I was hoping mostly to prevent the wrong types from being added to the list in the first place so that I could reliably cast objects which come out. I will use marker interfaces instead though